# requirejs r.js optimized builds of components over a main library

Tags: javascript, gwt, requirejs, js-amd, r.js

I'd like to get some best practice advice on componetising sub modules into a larger project. In development mode, it works fine as require resolves all deps on the fly - but it needs to be produced for a GWT app now that apparently has difficulty consuming async stuff via callbacks.

Structure is as follows (this builds fine individually and creates the files as required):

- main (builds all shared libs resources etc)

  - component A (requires main to be there but excluded in own build)
  - ... component N

To be used in an app that loads like so:

```
<script src='require.js'></script>
<script src='main-lib-min.js'></script>
<script src='component-a-min.js'></script>
<script src='component-n-min.js'></script>

<!-- client to all these files is a single app to kick off: -->
<script src='app.js'></script>
```

main is defined as a require wrap and fires an event when done. 
components are a collection of modules in a `define()` wrap.

the problem is, `app.js` should not reference anything until all references have been resolved. and `component-A` may have references to exports of `main-lib` so it should not be evaluated before the previous script has loaded.

in chrome, we are seeing parallel downloading and reference errors. need that to be blocking instead. since the `r.js` build has pre-packaged everything, the factory should be able to just return any module defined above it.

i.e. doing:

`var foo = require('foo');` ought to be fine.

if app.js is created as:

```
require(['foo'], function(foo){

});
```

then it works.

does anyone have experience in producing this kind of a component build / module pattern? would you include all modules from the main-lib build config as `modules: []` so they wait for each other? what if you want the client (i.e. the html file) to be the one adding the modules?

would you change the loading? is there a GWT loader that will be more appropriate to ensure sync-like behaviour? performance is not an issue.